# Applying different formatting to different description lists

Tags: formatting, lists

I'm using description lists for several different purposes in something I'm writing. I would like to somehow define these lists differently so that I could apply different formatting or style to the different types. In HTML/CSS I would use the "class" attribute to do this. Is there something similar that can be done in LaTeX? The only thing I could think of was to make sort of a wrapper \NewDocumentCommand or environment that would get the list passed to it as an argument.

EDIT:I meant the description environment. So sometimes I might want the descriptions on the same line as the items, other times offset on the next line. I know how to do this, but I don't want to have to do it individually for each list. The project may have as many as 240 description lists of three  different types.

I wanted to keep things flexible in case I had different ideas, but maybe I'm applying too much of an HTML/CSS mindset -- there I would use class attributes even if I had no specific plans to style things differently, just in case I wanted to do it later.

Comment: By "description" do you mean that you are really using the `description` environment?

Comment: Could you include some examples of the different styles you have in mind. If you are referring to the `description` environment, you might want to have a look at the `enumitem` package and its various list customization options.

Comment: Yes, let me edit the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `enumitem` offers the possibility of adapting the `description` environment and to define custom lists, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

% Define small caps description-like environment
\newlist{scdesc}{description}{1}
\setlist[scdesc]{font=\mdseries\scshape,noitemsep}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Foo] explanation for foo
\item[Bar] explanation for baz
\item[Baz] explanation for baz
\end{description}

\begin{description}[font=\slshape]
\item[Foo] explanation for foo
\item[Bar] explanation for baz
\item[Baz] explanation for baz
\end{description}

\begin{description}[font=\mdseries\scshape]
\item[Foo] explanation for foo
\item[Bar] explanation for baz
\item[Baz] explanation for baz
\end{description}

\begin{scdesc}
\item[Foo] explanation for foo
\item[Bar] explanation for baz
\item[Baz] explanation for baz
\end{scdesc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT** With the macro `\SetEnumitemKey` you can define a shorthand for a (more or less arbitrary) list of keys:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetEnumitemKey{myclassA}{font=\slshape,noitemsep}
\SetEnumitemKey{myclassB}{font=\mdseries\scshape,noitemsep}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[myclassA]
\item[Foo] explanation for foo
\item[Bar] explanation for bar
\item[Baz] explanation for baz
\end{description}

\begin{description}[myclassB]
\item[Foo] explanation for foo
\item[Bar] explanation for bar
\item[Baz] explanation for baz
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Right, but how would I apply these styles to multiple lists in a way that would let me change the style for all of them in one go? Like, I have 10 description environments of type A, and 10 of type B. I want to change it so all of type A have one style and all of type B have another style.

Comment: It is already given in the answer in first two lines where "type" `scdesc` is defined.

Comment: @ChrisKern Well, you just define three types of description with `\newlist` like I did with the `scdesc` in the example.

Comment: OK I think I see. That answers my question for the lists. But it sounds like there is no general purpose method like HTML's "class" attribute that could be used for any type of content.

Comment: Maybe my difficulty is just that my only experience with separating content and presentation before LaTeX was HTML/CSS, and so I'm just trying to transfer the way I did HTML/CSS over to LaTeX. This is probably a mistake.

Comment: @ChrisKern Are you saying you would like to have a `\begin{description}[myclass]` type of solution?

Comment: That sounds promising.

Comment: @ChrisKern See edit.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.